# How to grant extract DDL in Sybase to specific user?

Tags: sybase

I have a Sybase database and I've created a user following this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A4rQ4TzsoKM). Now I want to grant only select and get DDL permissions to the user, I've granted select permissions on all the user tables in the database to the user using `grant select on tableName to user_ro` query. But I'm not able to identify which permission will allow user to get DDL of all the database objects and can only read the data. What are the least privileges or roles that are needed to be granted to the user?
Queries that I ran against the database using SQL Interactive board:

```
//create login under master
use master
sp_addlogin user_ro, user1234

//verify user is created successfully
select name from syslogins

//add login user to mydatabase
use mydatabase
sp_adduser user_ro

//grant select on all tables one by one
grant select on tableName to user_ro
```

I'm quite new to Sybase, so please correct me wherever I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific DDL permission in ASE.

All programs that make DDL just select from system tables the definition of a certain object. So if you have access to some database and sp_help works then you can also create DDL from an object.

Comment: One slight addition to this there's an sp_configure option on later ASE versions ' select on syscomments.text ' which can also block users from being able to run sp_helptext if set to 0 which will prevent DDL extraction of views or stored procs.